# If T, S, linear operators, does TS upper triangular imply that both T and S are upper triangular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I think this is false, but am struggling to find a counterexample. Can anyone come up with a counterexample or proof?

Answer (score 2):

Take any nonsingular, non upper triangular matrix $A$. Then let $T=A$ and $S=A^{-1}$. We must have $TS=I$ upper triangular.

Answer (score 1):

For example: \begin{equation} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 2\\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}. \end{equation}
You can use Shur's theorem to find other examples.